# run command as different nologin user

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, sudo

I'm using the [maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) to execute an [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) command in order to copy a tar and extract it to a target directory on a remote server.

The command I run to extract it is:

```
/bin/sh -c 'tar -vxzf /path/to/${artifact}.tar.gz -C path/to/target/directory;'
```

This *used* to work fine until the owner of the target directory changed to a new user that is setup as nologin. I'm trying to figure out how to run this command as the new user.

I've tried to model it after [Basil A's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/362198/377329)

```
/bin/su -s /bin/sh -c 'tar -vxzf /path/to/${artifact}.tar.gz -C path/to/target/directory;' ${newUser}
```

But it prompts me for a password, which isn't going to work since its a nologin user.

Also, I'm not an expert on Linux but if I also just try to simply run this command from my home directory as the old user (which has sudo access), this fails

```
sudo -u ${newUser} tar -vxzf /path/to/${artifact}.tar.gz -C path/to/target/directory;
```

However, if I cd to the target directory and run that same exact command as the old user it works.  I'm guessing maybe if I understand this difference in behavior it will help me get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound to me like the issue here has anything to do with the new user being a system user or a no-login user. It sounds like the mostly likely explanation for what happened is that, since the owner of the target directory changed, there now isn't a user that has read permissions for the source directory and write permissions to the target directory.

Since you have sudo privileges on the host in question, you have a lot of options for how to resolve this.

1. You could give your original user write permissions to the target directory and run your `tar` command as that user.
2. You could give the new no-login user read permissions to the source directory and run your `tar` command as that user.
3. You could run the `tar` command with sudo and then set the ownership to be whatever you want it to be afterwards.

For example, something like the following should work:

```bsh
sudo tar -vxzf /path/to/${artifact}.tar.gz -C /path/to/target/directory

sudo chown -R "${newUser}:${newUser}" /path/to/target/directory
```

If you want to use a little more finesse and avoid having to run this as root, then you should update your question to include the permissions and ownership information for the directories in question as well as the group memberships of the relevant user accounts.